# Invalid Expression Pattern

Tags: regex, powershell

The following Regex pattern in PowerShell is giving me real trouble. The double and single quotes are the culprits but I don't know how to get PowerShell to accept it. How do I get PowerShell to successfully accept this pattern?

If I copy the pattern to a variable PowerShell complains about an unexpected token after the first quote found within the pattern.

```
$myRegex = "^param[\s?]*\([\$\sa-zA-Z\=\@\(\)\"\d\,\:\\\_\.\']*\)"
```

I then attempted to escape the double quote by adding another quote next to it. This time the string is accepted but the regex fails.  Notice the double double quote in the next example.

```
$myRegex = "^param[\s?]*\([\$\sa-zA-Z\=\@\(\)\""\d\,\:\\\_\.\']*\)"
$somelongString -replace $myRegex
```

**Error Message:**

```
The regular expression pattern ^param[\s?]*\([\$\sa-zA-Z\=\@\(\)\"\d\,\:\\\_\.\']*\) is not valid.
```

---

**Update 1:**
Per @Dan Farrell's suggestion I updated my regex as follows:

```
$myRegex = "^param(\s?)*\([\$\sa-zA-Z\=\@\(\)\""\d\,\:\\\_\.\']*\)"
```

---

**Update 2:**
This is a [working example](http://regexr.com/45s6c) of my Regex which I am trying to port to PowerShell

Comment: `[\s?]` ? You can't use character classes in character sets (they behave like sets themselves, so `(\s|\?)` is the correct way ) .

Comment: That appears to be a good tip but does not solve this issue.

Comment: Try ``$myRegex = "^param[\s?]*\([$\sa-zA-Z=@()`"\d,:\\_.']*\)"``, but it would be better if you explain what exactly you want to do with it. An example string with expected output would help. [Here is this pattern demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5eparam%5b%5cs%3f%5d*%5c%28%5b%24%5csa-zA-Z%3d%40%28%29%22%5cd%2c%3a%5c%5c_.%27%5d*%5c%29&i=param%3f%28var1+var2%2cvar3%29). The `"` and ``\_`` are the worst culprits in your code so far.

Comment: Append it with two string expressions, `$myRegex = "^param[\s?]*\([\$\sa-zA-Z\=\@\(\)\" + "\d\,\:\\\_\.\']*\)"`

Comment: There's several mistakes in your regex, and powershell is not helping much to find them, so take it out of the equation.  Start with a regex101 that has input data, then link that here and we can maybe help you fix a version.

Comment: @PrasoonKarunanV, anything you can write in 2 strings concatenated, you can write with one string unconcatenated so I'm not sure what you expect to gain there.  Also I think you're missing a quote.

Comment: You didn't accurately implement my suggestion.  And you didn't fix the other locations where you have a character class in a character set expression.  Regular expressions cannot be guessed through.  As a regex author, you have to understand each letter and why it's there.  Finally, w can't help without examples of the data and the results you wish to achieve, so start with that

Comment: If you do not  want to match `?` after `param`, use ``$myRegex = "^param\s*\([$\sa-zA-Z=@()`"\d,:\\_.']*\)"``. You have not added any test cases, so no idea if that pattern will work for you in the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Escaping `_` in a .NET regex causes an error. To use a `"` inside `"..."` string literal, you need to escape it with a backtick, use `` `" ``. Besides, you only need to escape `\` inside your character class.

Use

```
$myRegex = "^param\s*\([$\sa-zA-Z=@()`"\d,:\\_.']*\)"
```